# Prove that there exists $\alpha \neq \beta$ such that $|f(\alpha)-f(\beta)|\le \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $D \subset [0,1]$ is a set with at least $9$ elements, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_+^*$ such that $2a+b=2$ and $f:D\to \mathbb{R},\ f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Prove that there exists two numbers $\alpha, \beta\in D, \alpha \neq \beta$ such that:
>
> $$|f(\alpha)-f(\beta)|\le \frac{1}{4}$$

This is what I tried: With contradiction, suppose there are no such $\alpha, \beta$. Then, for any $\alpha, \beta\in D, \alpha \neq \beta$:

$$|f(\alpha)-f(\beta)| > \frac{1}{4}$$

and

$$|f(\alpha)-f(\beta)|=|a\alpha^2+b\alpha-a\beta^2-b\beta|=|(\alpha-\beta)(a(\alpha+\beta)+b)|$$

so

$$|(\alpha-\beta)(a(\alpha+\beta)+b)| > \frac{1}{4}$$

But I couldn't see the contradiction.

Comment: Do you know Dirichlet's principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on your efforts :

$$|(\alpha-\beta)(a(\alpha+\beta)+b)| > \frac{1}{4}$$

we have $|(\alpha-\beta)(a(\alpha+\beta)+b)|=|(\alpha-\beta)|(a(\alpha+\beta)+b)\leq |(\alpha-\beta)|(b+2a)$

$$|2(\alpha-\beta)|>|(\alpha-\beta)(a(\alpha+\beta)+b)| > \frac{1}{4}$$

which means $$|(\alpha-\beta)| > \frac{1}{8}$$

let $D= \{x_{1}<x_{2}<...<x_{9}..\}$

we have 
$$(x_{2}-x_{1})=|(x_{1}-x_{2})| > \frac{1}{8}$$
$$(x_{3}-x_{2})=|(x_{2}-x_{3})| > \frac{1}{8}$$
.
.
.
$$(x_{9}-x_{8})=|(x_{9}-x_{8})| > \frac{1}{8}$$

summing all these inequilities we get

$(x_{9}-x_{1})>1$

which is absurd , because $1\geq (x_{9}-x_{1})$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

By MVT,

$$f(\alpha)-f(\beta)=(\alpha-\beta)f'(d)$$

$$f'(d)=2ad+b\le f'(1)=2$$

you just need to prove that we cannot have

$$\forall x,y \in D  \;\; |x-y|>\frac 18$$
since $ D$ contains at least $9$ elements.